# Bootstrap modal is disabled when it is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular5

I use bootstrap 3.3.7 in my angular project and the modal is disabled when I open it by clicking "ADD CLASS".
My code is below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="add-class pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-class-modal">
  <img alt="+" src="assets/images/add.png" height="16px" width="16px" style="margin-top: -2px"><span class="add-a-class">ADD CLASS</span>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add-class-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result looks like this.
[image]

"ADD CLASS" button is at the top right corner.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like provided example works as expected, without some additional styling.

Comment: Its because it is pure bootstrap without any overrides, and i think that there are some additional styles which makes problem with z-indexing on real page.

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce the problem without additional details. The provided code works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't told you this. I use angular5 for my app

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and fixed it by adding `z-index` of the `.modal-backdrop` to negative value:

```
 // this is class for dialog itself
.modal-backdrop {
   position: relative;
   z-index: -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probaby you have some styling which makes that background overlay has larger z-index. Make sure your modal class has correct styling and dont have some additional onces. it should work fine with default bootstrap styling. You can try setting larger z-index to .modal, but the key is to check if you dont have some additional styling applied.

```
// this is class for dialog itself
.modal {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 9999
}
```

If z-index is smaller than 1072 it can be covered by gray background

UPDATE:

Based on bootstrap example modal on bootstrap page, looks like that gray background is created by div with class mocal-backdrop, which by default have such z-index:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 1071;
}
```

Comment: Making .modal-backdrop with smaller z-index than .modal z-index should work fine.